# Zend paginator view file not working

Tags: zend-framework, pagination

I'm trying to implement the paginator into my website.

Everything works until it hits this line

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'sliding', 'pagination.phtml'); ?>
```

For some reason it can't get to my pagination.phtml file.
There's nothing wrong with my $this->paginator because I used it in a foreach loop before this line.

The pagination.phtml file is located at application/views/pagination.phtml.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've deleted everything in pagination.phtml en replaced it with <?php echo 'test'; ?> but I still get an 'Application Error'

Comment: Alright I've got it, the pagination.phtml partial isn't suppose to be in the views folder but in the views/scripts folder. geez

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question. Could help others in future.